# API in wso2 identity server 5.7 to get fine grained access control list as a response if we pass role

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am new to WSO2 identity server. Need some help in getting the role-based access control list.

I have one angular application. In that there is a menu like product list, add product, update product, delete product. Based on the role defined in this application I want to show the menu items to the user. For example, we have roles like admin, manager, user. For the admin-role I have to show all the menu items. For manager-role show add-product, update-product and for the user-role only product-list menu item.

So when the user login into my application based on the user role I want to show the menu list. To authenticate, create users, roles, user role mapping I used SCIM2 APIs of wso2 identity server 5.7.

I tried XACML but not succeeded. Please help me how to get the Role-based ACL.

Comment: Which method did you try? This? https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Fine-grained+Authorization+using+XACML+Requests+in+JSON+Format

Answer (score 0):

First get an idea about XACML terms PEP, PDP, PAP, PIP [1][2] might help you. You can think about PEP (Policy Enforcement Point) as per your angular application. In order to communicate with XACML PDP, you can use XACML REST APIs [3]. Regarding writing XACML policies for RBAC, you can have a look already available XACML template **authn_role_based_policy_template**

[1] https://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2016/02/tutorial-how-to-enable-role-based-access-control-for-wso2-api-manager-using-xacml/

[2] https://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/11/fine-grained-xacml-authoriation-with-pip-points/

[3] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Using+REST+APIs+via+XACML+to+Manage+Entitlement

Comment: Thank you for sharing the info Gayan. If I use "authn_role_based_policy_template" or any XACML policy , when the user tries to access the service(or menu item) then only wso2is will allow the user to access that service based on the ACL defined in the policy. But my issue is -  once user logs in based on his role I want to show him the available services in the menu. So If I use XACML policy how could i get the list of permitted services to that particular role